# Выборка по ключу JSON

Tags: php, json

столкнулся с такой проблемой, нужно вывести значение json в цикле, вот пример json файла:

```
{
    "То, что нужно вывести":
    {
        "name":"Значение",
        "color":"#7282ff"
    }
}
```

Т.е, мне нужно получить "То, что нужно вывести", и еще значения по этому ключу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = '{"То, что нужно вывести": {"name":"Значение","color":"#7282ff"}}';

// получаем из json массив
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

// идем по массиву
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    echo '$key = '.$key.'<br />';   // здесь ключ - "То, что нужно вывести"
    echo '$val = <pre>'.print_r($val, true).'</pre>';   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsonobj = '{"Peter":35,"Ben": {"Joe":43}}';

$obj = json_decode($jsonobj);

echo $obj->Peter;
echo $obj->Ben->Joe;
```

На php можно вот так. **echo $obj->Ben->Joe;** выведется 43, а тут **echo $obj->Peter;** будет 35

Comment: Но мне же еще нужно найти "Peter" и "Ben"

Comment: ну да, но вы же знаете какой вам приходит json и потом его можно парсить. Чтобы не падали ошибки можно проверять существует ли значение в json if(isset($obj->Peter)) { echo $obj->Peter}

Comment: Я понятия не имею какой мне json приходит, + ключ может быть с пробелами

Comment: @XenozF Тоесть вы понятия не имеете с чем будете работать? Как вы тогда знаете  какие данные вам нужны?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру Ответ дан выше, под пользователем Максим Степанов

Comment: В Json ключи не могут быть пробелами. А как вы собираетесь работать с данным, не зная что вам приходит (хотя бы примерно)?

Comment: @XenozF Тогда указывайте ответ как правильный и поставьте плюсик автору. Ибо вы этот коментарий, на который я ответил, написали задолго после того как получили ответ.

Comment: @ВадимАлександру Я уже отметил ответ, и у меня репутация не позволяет ставить "Плюсик"